React UI doesn't show as expected on screen(instead is aligned to the left and missing styling)
Beginner here. I am trying to render a frontend page with React, but the result it's not as expected.
I had to ask here, as I couldn't find the solution myself.
You can see my result and how it should actually look like in the two pictures.
The files are copied into my own project from a tutorial.
I am expecting to see the same result as in the tutorial, but somewhere there is a disconnect and I can figure out why/where.
Project files in my GitHub [[repo]
Current result
How it should look like
Of course I can go manually and change all the displayed features to make it look nice like the reference, but I want to find what is missing when I copy these files in my project.
Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
